# Nginx - Global 500 page for all sites

Tags: nginx

I have a load balancer using nginx with multiple sites/servers. I would like to override the 404 and the 500/502 pages of all the sites being load balanced. Is there any way I can do that globally across sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `proxy_intercept_errors` to `on` and set `error_pages` directive accordingly.

> Determines whether proxied responses with codes greater than or equal
>   to 300 should be passed to a client or be intercepted and redirected
>   to nginx for processing with the error_page directive.

[Source](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors)